# scale buttons to screen size

Tags: android, android-layout

I have `RelativeLayout` with 3 `LinearLayouts` where I have buttons located. 2 button in each layout.
button sizes remain same on devices with different size: **Nexus 7 -** [image: http://i.imgur.com/rfCy2Me.png,]

**Nexus 5** - !

[image]

but I want buttons to resize for different screen sizes.
this is the source of layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/superviserlinearLayout1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:paddingTop="5dp">
    <Button
        android:text="აგენტები"
        android:id="@+id/superviserBtnAgents"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/admin"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="145dp" />
    <Button
        android:text="ობიექტები"
        android:id="@+id/superviserBtnObjects"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/store"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/superviserlinearLayout1"
    android:id="@+id/superviserlinearLayout2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    <Button
        android:text="დებიტორები"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/money"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="145dp"
        android:id="@+id/superviserBtnDebitors" />
    <Button
        android:text="საწყობი"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/production"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="145dp"
        android:id="@+id/superviserBtnDepot" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/superviserlinearLayout2"
    android:id="@+id/superviserlinearLayout3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    <Button
        android:text="ინკასაცია"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/atm"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="145dp"
        android:id="@+id/superviserBtnIncasation" />
    <Button
        android:text="შეტყობინებები"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/notes"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="145dp"
        android:id="@+id/superviserBtnNotes" />
</LinearLayout>
```

any suggestions how to achieve this?

**Edit:** I need background images to stretch, even if they appear pixelated.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: I checked that but how do I stretch/resize background images?

Comment: What i found is you have given
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
so it will only wrap the contents to its original size. Try having a linear layout instead of Relative Layout and use equal weights in each inner linear layouts

Comment: Don't fix the size of LinearLayout(Highet and width).. Rather use match_parent

Comment: Just resize the images in the drawable folder to the largest size you require. When used on smaller screens the image will auto resize to fit the small size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove the hardcoded width of buttons.
2. Change the LinearLayout width to `match_parent` instead of `wrap_content`, and use weight for buttons.

Something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/superviserlinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" 
        android:weightSum="2">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/superviserBtnAgents"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="145dp"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:text="აგენტები"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/superviserBtnObjects"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:text="ობიექტები"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/superviserlinearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/superviserlinearLayout1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:weightSum="2">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/superviserBtnDebitors"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="145dp"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:text="დებიტორები"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" 
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/superviserBtnDepot"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="145dp"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:text="საწყობი"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" 
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/superviserlinearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/superviserlinearLayout2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/superviserBtnIncasation"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="145dp"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:text="ინკასაცია"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" 
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/superviserBtnNotes"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="145dp"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:text="შეტყობინებები"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" 
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think that's exaclty what I needed, thanks.
I'll comment if anything.

Comment: is it possible to stretch images with buttons?

Comment: @misho for that you will need separate folders for drawables like hdpi, mdpi. As you have used drawableTop. If you use the background, it will stretch the image on whole button as background, but I am not sure if you want that way.

Answer (score 1):

To support different screen sizes you have to put appropriate sized images in the respective drawable folders, according to google these are the recommended sizes:

```
xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp (xxhdpi folder)
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp  (xhdpi folder)
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp (hdpi folder or mdpi (depends))
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp  (ldpi)
```

> Note: These minimum screen sizes were not as well defined prior to Android 3.0, so you may encounter some devices that are mis-classified between normal and large. These are also based on the physical resolution of the screen, so may vary across devices—for example a 1024x720 tablet with a system bar actually has a bit less space available to the application due to it being used by the system bar. -Google

Comment: Where did you get this information from. It looks like you copied it from and Android documentation, but the data in your brackets seems not to.

Comment: I clearly mention that these facts are from Google (android docs), the data in the brackets are also from Google but they are not listed side by side on their page.